# Localhost adding weird symbols to <a/> href in index page

Tags: html, hyperlink, localhost

In my index file in my localhost directory I have one  tag thats supposed to link to my projects folder.

```
<a href=“http://localhost/Projects/“>Projects</a>
```

When the page loads the  tag turns into this:

```
<a href="â€œhttp://localhost/Projects/â€œ">Projects</a>
```

What's going on?
Any fix ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like some sort of encoding problem

Comment: How are you inserting that double quotes? It seems to me that you want to use " and instead insert the one in the post (maybe copy paste from any app?)

Answer (score 2):

its a difference between “ and "
it should be 
`<a href="http://localhost/Projects/">Projects</a>` instead of

```
<a href=“http://localhost/Projects/“>Projects</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong quotes: use **"** instead of **“**. Also make sure you have set the charset of your document. If not, add this code into the `<head>` of your html page:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```